# Configuring a linux machine for high inbound network load

Tags: linux, networking

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 on an a dual processor Intel E5-2620-HexCore, 64GB of RAM, 1Gb network link.

When downloading a single test file from a location in the same datacenter (Public network) I get d/l rate of 80-100 MB/s (Bytes/second).

When crawling web pages using multi-process PHP design, no matter how many processes I run, the d/l rate stays steady on 200Mb/s (bits/second).
rate of packets per second is around 300K inbound.

I've tried some of the settings recommended here
http://http-kit.org/600k-concurrent-connection-http-kit.html
but that didn't make any difference.

Any ideas?

Comment: The large file download is apparantly limited by bandwidth and the other task runs into for instance a CPU or IO limit before reaching the bandwidth limit instead.

Comment: @Hbrujin hdparm shows my HD speed can get to 150MB/s write, where iotop shows current load of only 2M/s. cpu and memory load are not even close to their limit. so that's probably not the issue.

Comment: hdparm  is a horrible tool for testing hard drive performance.  You really should be using something like bonnie++, or iometer.  `hdparm -t` is a sequential raw-read operation, it doesn't tell you anything about the writes, or random access.  It also completely ignores the filesystem overhead.

Comment: @Zoredache bonnie++ shows a not so different rate of 137MB/s. how does this rate limit d/l rate in any way?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the firewall that is between your server and the internet? I know most firewalls will have default limits on packets and concurrent connections for any single host inside or outside the network. Especially if the firewall comes with IDS.